A proof for a formula of Gauss
At pg. 35-36 of the book The Summation of Series by Davis, Harold T. there is the following formula of Gauss
For $1 \leq a < q$:
$$
\psi\left( \frac{a}{q} \right) = -\gamma - \log q - \frac{\pi}{2} \cot\left( \frac{a\pi}{q} \right) + \sum_{b=1}^{r} \cos\left( \frac{2\pi ab}{q} \right) \log \left( 4 \sin^2 \left( \frac{\pi b}{q} \right) \right) + (-1)^a \log 2 \left( 1 + (-1)^q \right),
$$
where $r := \left\lfloor \frac{q-1}{2} \right\rfloor$.
I tried a lot to prove it myself but couldn't and tried to find a proof of it online also I couldn't find any. How can I find the proof of this?
